# How to use the component Webix Uploader to upload a file, changing its name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, webix

I'm trying to pass through the options, but do not know how to process them on the server side. The file is loaded without problems.
I created a form:

```
webix.ui({
    view: "form",
    borderless: true,
    elements: [
        {view: "text", label: 'User', name: "user",invalidMessage:"User can not be empty"},
        {view: "text", label: 'Name', name: "name",invalidMessage:"Name can not be empty"},
        {view: "text", label: 'Email', name: "email",invalidMessage:"Incorrect e-mail address"},
        {view: "text", label: 'Key', name: "key",invalidMessage:"Key can not be empty"},
        {
            view:"uploader",
            id: "fileUploader",
            value:"Upload key",
            autosend:false,
            upload:"api/upload"
        },
        {
            view: "button", value: "Submit", click: function () {
            var form = this.getParentView();
                if (form.validate()){

                    var values = this.getParentView().getValues();

                    $$('fileUploader').send(function(res){

                    },{
                        fileName:values.user
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    rules:{
        "user": webix.rules.isNotEmpty,
        "name": webix.rules.isNotEmpty,
        "email": webix.rules.isEmail,
        "key": webix.rules.isNotEmpty
    },
    elementsConfig: {
        labelPosition: "top"
    }
});
```

I'm using server node.js

```
app.post('/api/upload/', function(req,res) {

    fs.readFile(req.file.path, function (err, data) {
        var newPath = __dirname + "/uploads/"+req.file.originalname;
        fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
            res.send("ok");
            fs.unlink( __dirname + "/uploads/"+req.file.filename);

        });
    });
}
);
```

Or are there any options to change the name before send()?

Answer (score 0):

File name is readonly can can't be changed
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Your server side code can be optimized though, instead of fs.readFile, fs.writeFile, fs.unlink why not use a fs.rename. A single command to move the uploaded file to the correct name and location.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the name before sending the file but could not.

so:

```
function renameFile(req, res)
{
    var name = post.name;
    var type = post.type
    fs.rename(__dirname+'/'+name, __dirname+'/'+createStringDate(name), function(err) {
        if ( err ) 
        {
            console.log("!!!***LOG_:renameFile-Error(500): ".red+err);
            res.status(500).json(err);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("***LOG_:renameFile-Respuesta(200): Archivo renombrado.".magenta);
            res.status(200).json("Estatus:Ok");
        }
    });
};
function createStringDate()
{
  //create string date
  return "yyyymmdd"
}
```

JS file must be saved in the folder where you save the document.